# HTTPS множество серверов на разных портах. Как настроить?

Tags: apache, nginx, https

У меня есть различные серверы и мне надо всех их запустить на одной машине. А сертификаты же одни. Надо использовать один и тот же? Как поступить, никогда так не делал.
Все должно быть по протоколу HTTPS

Comment: Разве номер порта используется в сертификате?

Comment: @Qwertiy, мне можно указывать один сертификат для каждого сервера так? Ну я  не знаю об этом еще

Answer (score 1):

В конфигурации nginx общие настройки ssl можно вынести в секцию http:

```
http {
    ssl_certificate             xyz.ssl.chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key         xyz.ssl.key;
    ssl_dhparam                 dhparam.pem;
    ssl_protocols               TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers                 ...;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
    ssl_session_cache           shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout         10m;
    ssl_stapling                on;

    server {
        listen          443 ssl http2;
        server_name     site.ru;

        location /service1/ {
            proxy_pass    http://localhost:12000;
            ...
        }
        location /service2/ {
            proxy_pass    http://localhost:12010;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

В зависимости от задач остальные настройки можно смотреть тут [ngx_http_proxy_module](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html), а если используется fastcgi то тут [ngx_http_fastcgi_module](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html) (заменив `proxy_pass` на `fastcgi_pass`).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37612/discussion-on-answer-by-norbornen-https------).

Answer (score 0):

Соединение HTTPS устанавливается ДО того, как собственно запрос поступит в WEB сервер, будет разобран на составляющие части и станет понятно, к какому из виртуальных серверов его надо направить.
Соответственно, браузер должен провести проверку HTTPS сертификата еще до того, как направит сам запрос на сервер. Проблема.
Если на WEB сервере хостится несколько виртуальных сайтов, то надо использовать wildcard сертификат, т.е. в нем подтверждается имя вида *.domain.com. Такой сертификат будет работать на любом из сайтов домена domain.com. 
Возможно также частные случаи, например в сертификате можно указать только конкретные имена виртуальных сайтов.